# Difference between () & [] in R

Tags: r

When I write the following:

```
tempx <- tempx (-1, c(-4, -2:-20))
```

I get the following error message:

> Could not find function "tempx"

But when I write the following the code runs properly:

```
tempx <- tempx [-1, c(-4, -2:-20)]
```

Please let me know the diff between `()` & `[]`.

Comment: () indicates a function - see mean(5), [] indicates subsetting, see ?"[".

Comment: there is no need to put a space before the ( or [

Answer (score 2):

`()` is used to call a function. `[]` is used for subsetting vectors, arrays and matrices (and other such objects).

I'd suggest if you haven't already, reading [an introduction to R](http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), also available by typing `help.start()` into R itself. In particular, you might like to look at sections **2.1 Vectors and assignment** and **5.2 Array indexing. Subsections of an array**.